# Why I can't change the variable value from callback event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, scope

## Scenario One (the question)

---

#### POST request To /radikpidr

> `headers: nothing special`
>
> `body: pidr=radik`

#### POST response From /radikpidr

> `headers: nothing special`
>
> `body: pidr=radik`

#### expectation(NOT MET):

> Print request body content into the console.

#### reality(FRUSTRATING):

> Varibale [body] was not changed since initialisation, as it seems.

#### note:

> I've got the request body content in response to my request, which is imposible to achieve without changing body (variable)

---

```js
const app = require("express")();

let body = "not as expected";

app.post("/radikloh", (req,res)=>{
    req.on("data",function(chunk){
        body = chunk.toString();
    });
    
    console.log(body)//"not as expected"

    req.on("end",function(){
        res.send(body);
    });

    console.log(body)//"not as expected"
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

---

## Scenario Two (a solution)

---

#### POST request To /radikpidr

> `headers: nothing special`
>
> `body: pidr=radik`

#### POST response From /radikpidr

> `headers: nothing special`
>
> `body: pidr=radik`

#### expectation(MET):

> Print request body content into the console.

#### reality(more or less Satisfying):

> Just as expected

---

```js
const app = require("express")();

let body = "not as expected";

function buff (input){
    body = input;
}

app.post("/radikloh", (req,res)=>{
    req.on("data",function(chunk){
        body = chunk.toString();
        buff(body);
    });
    
    console.log(body)//"pidr=radik"
    
    req.on("end",function(){
        res.send(body);
    });
    
    console.log(body)//"pidr=radik"
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

---

## THE QUESTION IS WHY ?

I thought this is because of a callback function scope but it works fine in this expample:

```js
function a (cb){
    cb("It worked just FINE");
}
function b (){
    let body = "not as expected";
    
    a(function(seter){
        body = seter;
    });
    
    console.log(body);//THE OUTPUT: "It worked just FINE"
}
```

---

And even in this:

```js
let body = "not as expected";
function a (cb){
    cb("It worked just FINE");
}
function b (){

    
    a(function(seter){
        body = seter;
    });
    
    console.log(body);//THE OUTPUT: "It worked just FINE"
}
```

Comment: What happens when you log the body after this line `body = chunk.toString();` in the first scenario and in the second log the value of body after this line `body = chunk.toString();` and in `buff` function after `body = input;`?

Comment: Have you tried `var body = "not as expected"`;

Comment: Yes, I tried. If I'll print `body` from a callback function it will work as expected in both scenarios , regardless of variable type (var or let).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check this out on node site about [request body](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body)

```
let body = [];
request.on('data', (chunk) => {
  body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', () => {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
});
```

Are you sending data when you make a POST request ? if body remains the same then it may be not entering the req.on('data'.. function

Comment: you should probably answer the question in the answer in addition to fixing the code and supplying a resource.

Comment: You are right. This kind of consequences caused by the use of body variable(in this case i was printing in into the console) before req.on event is fired up. I check this version by using timeout function on console.log(body) and it worked as predicted.